# how to prompt a delete confirmation inside the php echo with an image inside an a tag link

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have done this code in viewstudents.php the deletion process worked with the image but I'm not able to do the javascript part inside php inside the echo i mean can someone help me out. here is my code:

```
 <?php
session_start();
include("connection.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
    header("location:login.php");
$qry="SELECT * FROM studentinformation";

$result= mysqli_query($con,$qry) or die (mysqli_error($con));
echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['user'];
echo "<table border =1 width=80%><tr><td>FullName</td><td>Email</td><td>Password</td></tr>";

while($i = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$i['FullName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$i['email']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$i['Password']."</td> ";
    echo "<td><a href=DeleteStudentAction.php?Key=".$i['ID']."onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" ><img src = delete-1432400-1211078.png style = width:35px;hight:20px;> </img> </a></td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";




?>
```

it worked fine with the image but I want to have a confirmation prompt that's not working can someone help me out please. Here is my php action for deletion from the database in DeleteStudentAction.php

I really appreciate if someone would help me out because I'm new to php. Thanks!

Comment: Check your rendered output your html is going to be malformed, eg your href attribute is combining with your onclick attribute thus the parser isnt going to see that as a onclick attribute but rather a long url instead

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: Always `exit()` after `header('Location: ...');` Your code is going to be execute even if the user is not logged in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't got quotes around your href, try this:

```
while($i = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo '<tr>
        <td>' . $i['FullName'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $i['email'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $i['Password'] . '</td>
        <td>
            <a href="DeleteStudentAction.php?Key=' . $i['ID'] . '" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')">
                <img src="delete-1432400-1211078.png" style="width:35px; height:20px;" />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>';

}
```

Comment: should i put it like this inside the echo

Comment: echo "<td><a href=\"DeleteStudentAction.php?Key=".$i['ID']."\" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" ><img src = delete-1432400-1211078.png style = width:35px;hight:20px;> </img> </a></td>";

Comment: i did it like this and it said that there is an error on line 17 which is this line

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: The doctor said that href could also work without quotes i asked him in class

Comment: Yes, but this is very bad practice, and in this case it is merging with another attribute on the tag. E.g. href=linkonclick=.

Comment: If this has worked, remember to mark this answer as correct, thank you.

Comment: Instead of messing with echo and making sure to use escaping either use heredoc syntax or just render html outside the php tags and echo the actual dynamic parts, eg `?><html...><a href="url...<?php echo $i['ID'];?>" onclick="`

Comment: @MoustafaAsaad href and other attributes can work without quotes but quotes help keep attributes separate from each other and prevent situations like you encountered where your attributes were merging into each other

Comment: one more question whats the backslash in php what does it do is it like the break in java ?

Comment: It is an escape character it tells the parser to not process the next character as a token character of the language. In this case dont process the quote as a string delimiter but as an actual part of the string itself